# автоматическое обновление токена в C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Есть сервис, который после авторизации предоставляет токен на 24 часа, нужно в автоматическом режиме обновлять токен раз в стуки в ASP.NET. Проект не CORE. Есть идеи или решения как это можно реализовать?

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Постановка задачи озвучена понятно. Не знаете, как с токенами работать или с транспортом?

Comment: Знаю как работать с токеном. Пока не могу сообразить как реализовать автоматическое обновление токена.

Comment: Тогда тут ответ @brun0 вполне подходит: в случае HTTP получаете 403 (Unauthorized) - пробуете обновить токен и повторить прежний запрос.

Comment: Есть обработчик Page_Load()(обработчик перехода на страницу), есть функция GetToken()(получение токена) и SendInfo()(отправка информации POST методом в сервис, в хедере токен).

Comment: Сервис возвращает 401 ошибку. И еще как инициировать самый первый токен?

Comment: А в чем проблема с первым токеном? Что нужно передать в `GetToken`, чтобы сгенерить новый?

Comment: Ничего передавать не нужно этот метод пока умеет только отправлять на сервер логин пароль и получать токен.

Comment: Клиент должен быть в курсе, есть ли у него токен, если нет - запросить.

Comment: В таком случае, при обращении к странице каждый раз так будет генерироваться новый токен, тогда какой смысл автоматически обновлять.

Comment: Токен нужно хранить между запросами и запрашивать его только в двух случаях: его еще нет или если старый уже протух.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуй, удобно было бы обновлять токен при получении ответа с ошибкой о том, что токен устарел. Обновляете токен, затем повторяете первый запрос с уже обновленным токеном.

Comment: redis + ответ @brun0 решил мой вопрос.

Comment: в redis можно указать время жизни токена. И при каждом обращении проверять на наличие токена, если нет то запросить новый и записать.